# Spring-Boot without STOMP (raw websocket)

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

**Edit: Please do not downvote without leaving at least a comment.**

I'd like to implement websocket in a SpringBoot application without Message Broker and STOMP. However, I need to access Spring Beans (repositories and services).

The [Java API](http://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets) is so simple that I can't understand why Spring made it so complex.

Here's what I need:

I need to implement a websocket endpoint with dynamic URI so I can use `@PathParam` like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{username}")
public class wsEndpoint
```

Using `@EnableWebSocket` with `WebSocketConfigurer` and `TextWebSocketHandler` only allows me to implement static endpoints.

The alternative recommended by [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) is to implement Message Brokers and STOMP, which makes usage (IMHO) unnecessarily complex for most cases.

I really would like to use `@EnableWebSocket` with `WebSocketConfigurer`,  `TextWebSocketHandler` and dynamic URIs. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Why people downvote questions without any comment?

Comment: Are you in a Java EE environment? If yes, can you use Spring beans in a standard websocket implementation (Tyrus implementation of the JSR-356)?

Comment: @Al1 AFAIK I can't because a standard websocket would not be a Spring bean itself, so I can't autowire anything.

Comment: Correcting myself. Just remembered I can add the standard websocket as a Bean through a configuration class, so yes. I can autowire things in there.
But anyway my question regards to dynamic URIs.